# Login/Logout with Action Bar/Menu Item

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a single menu item that shows up in my action bar and I would like it to display "Log In" or "Log Out" depending on whether the user is logged in or logged out. However, I cannot get it to change text because in order to do so I have to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` from inside my `onOptionsSelected()` method. I currently have a method that updates the text that should show, and this works fine, but in order to display that text I have to recreate the options menu.

Here is some of my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    updateMenuTitles();
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.login:
            if (!loggedIn) {
                Authentication();
            } else {
                loggedIn = false;
                authentication = false;
                updateMenuTitles();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Log Out Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateMenuTitles() {
    MenuItem bedMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.login);
    if (loggedIn) {
        bedMenuItem.setTitle("Log Out");
    }else {
        bedMenuItem.setTitle("Login");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using firebase, I'm checking if user is null or not. Based on that I'm adding which menu option I need.
Something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    if (firebaseUser!=null){
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.landing_logout,menu);
    }else {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.landing_login, menu);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to have two different buttons in your menu and switch their visibility according to the needs.
Something like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                 loggedIn = true;
                 Authentication();
                 updateMenuTitles();
            break;

            case R.id.logout:
                loggedIn = false;
                authentication = false;
                updateMenuTitles();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Log Out Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void updateMenuTitles() {
    MenuItem loginMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.login);
    MenuItem logoutMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.logout);

    if (loggedIn) {
        loginMenuItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logoutMenuItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        logoutMenuItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loginMenuItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `setVisibility` on `MenuItem`

Comment: Yes you can, check the documentation:(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setVisible(boolean))

Comment: That's `setVisible` which doesn't have a `GONE` option which is what you'd need, and it doesn't work with the boolean values. All it does is prevent me from clicking the button.

Comment: Have you tried?? I just made a test and it does hide the button